# How to install Tensorflow in base environment on Anaconda?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda, data-science

Using Python 3.9.7(64-bit).

[Gets forever to install the packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCfm7.png)

After installing, it shows which environment to download Tensorflow in. After I choose 'base' it loads for sometime and gives out error.

What can be wrong ??

Comment: Some people have downvoted you because they think you just need to activate the base environment. But it doesn't work. It only allows you to install it on a different environment, not directly on the base.
The same problem happens with Keras.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Tensorflow over the terminal.

Step 1:
`conda activate base`

Step 2:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

If this installation command doesn't work, here is the official link to the [Anaconda forum](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow). There you will find more commands you could try out.
If none of those things work out I would try to reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.
It only allows you to install it on a different environment, not directly on the base.